# How to convert excel files (xslx files) to pdf in the sharepoint web part?

Tags: c#, pdf, sharepoint-2010, xlsx

I am developing sharepoint web part. I have customized sharepoint server ribbon. Sharepoint server ribbon now includes one button. On clciking on this button I am downloading the xlsx files in sharepoint library to one of my local drive. Now I want to convert this downloaded xlsx file into pdf file. Then I want to upload this pdf file to one document library in sharepoint. For customizing the server ribbon and handling the button postback I am using the following link in which code sample is provided for download

[Customizing and Extending the SharePoint 2010 Server Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg552606.aspx)

The code sample is working fine for me. I have dowloaded the xlsx files to local folder. Now I want to convert this downloaded xlsx files which are on local folder to pdf files So I am using the following link

[Convert xlsx file to pdf file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1670775.aspx/1)

The code sample given in the above link is also working file for me in console application. I am able to convert xlsx files to pdf files in console application.But when I done the copy and paste of the code into the sharepoint project it is not working. I am not able to understand why the same code is not working in sharepoint project ? The code is as follows

```
        SautinSoft.UseOffice u = new SautinSoft.UseOffice();

        //Path to any local file
        string inputFilePath =  "D:\\a.xlsx";
        //string inputFilePath = "http://shailesh-pc/TemplateInvoice/Template.xlsx";
        //Path to output resulted file
        string outputFilePath = "D:\\afadfasfd.pdf";
        //string outputFilePath = "http://shailesh-pc/Invoice/aa.xlsx";


        //Prepare UseOffice .Net, loads MS Excel in memory
        int ret = u.InitExcel();

        //Return values:
        //0 - Loading successfully
        //1 - Can't load MS Excel library in memory 

        if (ret == 1)
            return;

        //Converting
        ret = u.ConvertFile(inputFilePath, outputFilePath, SautinSoft.UseOffice.eDirection.XLSX_to_PDF);




        //Release MS Excel from memory
        u.CloseExcel();

        //0 - Converting successfully
        //1 - Can't open input file. Check that you are using full local path to input file, URL and relative path are not supported
        //2 - Can't create output file. Please check that you have permissions to write by this path or probably this path already used by another application
        //3 - Converting failed, please contact with our Support Team
        //4 - MS Office isn't installed. The component requires that any of these versions of MS Office should be installed: 2000, XP, 2003, 2007 or 2010
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            //Show produced file
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputFilePath);
        }
```

In the sharepoint project I am getting the value 0 at `int ret = u.InitExcel();` But I am getting the value 1 at line `ret = u.ConvertFile(inputFilePath, outputFilePath, SautinSoft.UseOffice.eDirection.XLSX_to_PDF);`in the sharepoint project. Why this is happening. Is there any probelm with sharepoint project so that they are not able to convert xlsx files to pdf ? Can you please tell me what should I need to do to convert xlsx files in pdf in sharepoint? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can convert the xlsx files to pdf files ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Microsoft doesn't recommend Office automation in such scenarios:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

You may check further details in the following topic: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757. So, it is better to consider alternatives.